# Parsing continued-multiline data in Python

Tags: python, file, escaping

I am trying to read data using python, but my data like this

```
foo = first, second, ... \
fifteen, sixteen
```

The `\` at the end is supposed to make the data one line.  However, python does not do this with `readline()` so how would I get python to treat the `\` as a line continuation?

Comment: `f.read().replace('\\\n', '').split('\n')`? Assuming no whitespace between the backslash and the newline

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the new line instruction. Which is:

```
\n
```

code would be like:

```
mstring = mtring.replace("\n", "")
```

Sometimes `\r` is used as new line instruction, I am not really sure when. But replacing  `\n` must work.

Comment: `\r\n` is the Windows line ending, `\n` is used on *nix systems. See http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/29075/4307

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this: Instead of using `readline` you can use `read` to read all file at once. then use split

```
with open("your_file") as f:
    f = f.read()
    my_lines = f.split("\\")
```

Comment: Other way 'round I think... Combine the `\\` lines, not split them